elasticsearch query-result has 2 sizes,but aggs-result is null
enter image description here
As picture,ES  query-result has 2 sizes,but aggs-result is null and no error-result,why? what's happen?
i want to the reason.
GET XXXX/_search
{
  "_source": "title_md5",
  "size": 10,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "term": {
            "platform.website_name": "XXX"
          }
        },{
          "range": {
            "publish_time": {
              "gte": "2024-07-30 XX:XX:00",
              "lte": "2024-07-31 XX:00:00"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "aggs_title": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "title_md5",
        "size": 10
      }
    }
  }
}


Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors? I also suggest that you take the [tour] and read [ask].
